# New line not rendering from template tag in HTML

Tags: html, django, django-templates, newline, templatetags

I have a set of information to be rendered on my webpage using django template tags.

```
 {% for product in sales %}

      <div>
        <span>Customer:{{product.to_user}}</span><br>
        <span>{{product.time}}</span><br>
        <p class="message">{{product.message}}</p>
      </div>

      {% endfor %}
```

The `{{product.message}}` template tag contains information separated by new line('\n'). But, newlines are not rendered in HTML, the information is displayed in a single line omitting to obey '\n'.
I tried capturing the information from the `<p>` tag and replacing `\n`, with `<br>`, and again setting the text in the same `<p>` tag. But it doesn't seem to work.
This was my approach, as stated above.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      let renderedText = $(".message").text()

      //alert(renderedText)
      final_txt = renderedText.replace(/\n/g,"<br>")

      $(".message").val(final_txt)
       
    })
```

What changes or addition should I make, in order to get this working?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally a new line *is* replaced by Django by a `<br>`, unless you set `autoescape` *off* (but by default, it is on): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape.

Comment: I verified if there are newlines('\n')  present in the text body or not, by doing ```alert(renderedText)``` , and the alert message did show newlines at the expected places. So, what's causing the issue in HTML?

Comment: are you sure these are new lines, and not `'\\n'` (so a backslash *character* followed by *n*). Notice there is a difference between `'\\n'` and `'\n'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the template filter [linebreaksbr](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr) like so :

```
<p class="message">{{ product.message|linebreaksbr }}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly fine now. My bad, I had never come across the ```linebreaksbr```  filter.

Comment: No problem ! It's a useful one. You may be interested in the simple `linebreaks` which create a `<p>` tag for paragraph when there are two new lines.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have the line information you can use ***pre tag*** to keep track of empty spaces and new line.

```js
let message = `Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text Lorem ipsum text.
Lorem ipsum textLorem ipsum text

Lorem ipsum textLorem ipsum textLorem ipsum textLorem ipsum textLorem ipsum textLorem ipsum textLorem ipsum textLorem ipsum textLorem ipsum text`;
```

```html
<div><pre>{message}</pre></div>
```